# How long should you keep an ODBC SQL connection open?

Tags: sql, oracle, winapi, odbc

A long-running application uses the MS C OBDC API to create and use SQL connections to an Oracle DB. The application was originally designed to establish an ODBC connection at startup and keep that connection indefinitely as the application runs, potentially for weeks or months.

We're seeing very infrequent cases where a connection suddenly dies and I wondered if that's because we're using them wrong, or if it's considered OK to hold a connection like this. Can anyone point me to some definitive information on the subject?

Comment: Could you explain what your application does?

Comment: Not in detail but I can say it consists of many separate applications running on server/client PCs, which all communicate with a DB on a separate server. Processes run for months but none are continually accessing the DB in a high-load way... any specific process might access the DB only a few times a minute at the very most (often much less).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's definitive information regarding this, but with long-running programs you always have to be prepared for this kind of incidents, they just happen (and not only with db connections but also with sockets that remain open for extended periods).  I have no experience with Oracle, but I have a very similar setup with Informix, and this is (in pseudocode) what we do

```
while (programissupposedtorun) {
    opendb();
    do {
       youractivities();
    } while(dbisok);
    closedbandcleanup();
}
```

As long as you are able to correctly detect that the connection died and are able to resume processing without losing data you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ODBC but such use cases are best handled with a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). Your application can simply request a connection from the pool when it has some work and release it as soon as its done -- the pool will take care of actually (re)connecting to the database.

A quick search for ODBC connection pooling brought this up: [Driver Manager Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What I don't understand here is how pooling works with prepared statements... every time you ask for a connection you would surely have to re-prepare the statement which slightly defies the point of it.

Comment: Connection pools are meant for applications which have a lot of users who need to communicate with the database intermittently, for short periods of time and to undertake discrete units of work.  In other words, the classic OLTP application.  It is not at all clear that this is the OP's scenario.

Comment: @John: Yes, but the cost of preparing a statement is insignificant unless you're running the same query hundreds of times a second. Database connections are much more expensive to create/maintain and a pool can manage this efficiently for you.

Comment: @APC: True, that's the primary use of connection pools, but managing long-lived connections / reconnections is a task that pools already do well, so why not reuse that functionality instead of rolling out a custom solution?